# Cannot use GETDEC for the life of me

Tags: assembly, masm, dosbox

Ive been bagging my head against a wall for 2 hours just trying to figure out how to get a int using getdec and Google has been no help to me at all. The book im using only gives a definition of getdec as well as its inputs and output but no examples on how it is used.

I have to get several ints from the user by using get dec and pushing them on the stack. I know getdec is supposed to take a input and store in in AX. Im also not allowed to use any dot operations.

I make the file using `ML /Fl p3.asm /link io.lib
pause` so i know that lib.io is included.

So far ive only got this:

```
`DOSSEG`

    DATA SEGMENT
    NAM     BYTE    'xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx' ;LEN 19-CHANGE NAME AND LEN
    HEADER  BYTE    'Enter a number' 
    ZEROS WORD 0000
    DATA ENDS
    CODE    SEGMENT 'CODE'
    ASSUME CS:CODE, SS:NOTHING, DS:DATA, ES:NOTHING
    P3: MOV AX,SEG DATA
     MOV DS,AX
    call GETDEC
    PUSH AX
;rest of code goes here


    CODE ENDS
     END P3
```

Im good on using the stack and asthmatic but i simply cant get the input using getdec.

Comment: You know that that `GETDEC` is nothing ordinary, and without specifying the book you are using we have no idea what you are talking about? It's not part of "x86 Assembly", but code made by the author of the book. In the linking you add that external code by linking "io.lib" to your code, so you have to use Assembler directives to interconnect those external symbols between different modules. Also don't spend too much time memorizing these external functions, as they are relevant only to this book, focus on the instructions and principles, those apply with some modifications also elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! If anyone else is having issues you must include `EXTERN GETDEC:FAR` at the beginning of the program.